# How to select gridpanel row as HTMLELEMENT in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I want to select a grid row (HtmlElement) and try to apply css class on it.
but unable to select row in grid in extjs 4.

I select a row on checkboxSelectionModel pattern and looking to add/delete cls.
In 1.X extjs, Code look like that;

```
function UncheckCheckHeader(control)
{
var grid=<%=grdForms.ClientID%>;
var hd =Ext.get(grid.getView().getHeaderCell(0).childNodes[0]); 

var store = grid.store; 

if(store.getCount()== control.getCount()) 
{
if(!hd.hasCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on'))
{
hd.addCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
}
}
else
{
if(hd.hasCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on'))
{
hd.removeCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
}
}
}
```

and Header Click is :

```
<HeaderClick Fn="function(ct, column, e, t, eOpts )
                                             {    debugger;                  
                                                if(column.getIndex() == 0)
                                                {
                                                  var hd = Ext.fly(e.target.parentNode);

                                                  var isChecked = hd.hasCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
                                                  var showSelectedOn=false;
                                                  if(!showSelectedOn)
                                                  {
                                                    if(isChecked)
                                                    {
                                                      selectionHeaderChecked=true;
                                                      #{checkSelectionModel}.setLocked(false);
                                                      #{checkSelectionModel}.selectAll();
                                                      #{checkSelectionModel}.setLocked(true);
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                      selectionHeaderChecked=false;
                                                      #{checkSelectionModel}.setLocked(false);
                                                      #{checkSelectionModel}.deselectAll();
                                                      #{checkSelectionModel}.setLocked(true);
                                                    }  
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                    if(!selectionHeaderChecked)
                                                    {
                                                      hd.addCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                      hd.removeCls('x-grid3-hd-checker-on');
                                                    }
                                                  }         
                                                }                                                                                    
                                              }" />
```

I have an ExtJs Grid with CheckBoxSelectionModel. Selecting the header checkbox checks all the records and deselecting the checkbox unchecks all the records, of course which is the behavior. My grid has a delete button to delete the selected/all records and is working fine.

Now my problem is, when I check the checkbox at the header (so that entire records will be selected) and hits my delete button, the entire records in the grid is getting deleted. But, the checkbox selection in the column header still remains as checked.

I used the code: grid.getSelectionModel().DeSelectAll(); to clear selection, after deletion. I guess, this code is only applicable to records in the grid and has nothing to do with the column header part. Is there any way, I can deselect the chekbox in the header?

On a detailed investigation, I's surprised to know that the checkbox displayed in the CheckBoxSelectionModel is not html checkboxes, but they are images. So my idea of deselecting the checkbox using the DOM concept cannot be applied here. Instead, some kinda CSS trick has to be done.

Does anyone faced such an issue before? Is there any solution for this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for header cell here...

Answer (score 0):

We can do in many way, please refer below

```
var summaryRow = grid.getView().getFeature(0); 
styleObj = {
     'background-color': '#c5c5c5'  
 };
summaryRow.view.el.setStyle(styleObj);
```

Or

```
var summaryRow = grid.getView();
styleObj = {
         'background-color': '#c5c5c5'  
};
summaryRow.addRowCls(<index>, styleObj);
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks you are right but I need to access this 'x-grid-hd-checker-on' class to Select/Deselect ALL grid rows.

Comment: Okay, to solve your plm, i need to walk through your code structure. Better refer below example link http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html I hope that u will get that code in your extjs sdk package, for your reference see the path at /examples/grid/grid-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

My understanding : You want to add and remove css based on selection.You could do this using :

```
  grid.getView().addRowCls(rowindex, "yourCssClass" );
```

And remove your css using :

```
grid.getView().removeRowCls("rowindex","yourCssClass");
```

> You could use above in **selectiononchange** and **deselect** event listeners of grid.It is upto you how to play with them.Thanks.